# Reading Dicts and Lists in Django template

Tags: python, django

Could someone please help me with django template system. This is my setup in views:

```
html_vars = {
             'some_var1': 'some_val1',
             'some_var2': 'some_val2',
             'cat': {
                     't_cat21' : { 'cats': ['val21_1', 'val21_2', 'val21_3'], 'info': 'text21' },
                     't_cat22' : { 'cats': ['val22_1', 'val22_2', 'val22_3'], 'info': 'text22' },
                     't_cat23' : { 'cats': ['val23_1', 'val23_2', 'val23_3'], 'info': 'text23' },
                    },
            }

def home(request):
    render_to_response('home.html', html_vars)
```

I want to get this result in html:

```
t_cat21 (text21) - val21_1, val21_2, val21_3
t_cat22 (text22) - val22_1, val22_2, val22_3
t_cat23 (text23) - val23_1, val23_2, val23_3
```

But I'am having problems at reading data from django template. I understand the starting point:

```
{% for category, values in cat.items %}
  {{ category }}
  ???
{% endfor %}
```

And then I'm stuck (

**UPDATE**

Thanks for help. Unfortunately cannot vote the answer yet.

Comment: I think, the `cat.items` in your template shall read `cat.items()`

Comment: @JanVlcinsky Templates in Django use a simplified lookup mechanism, automatically executing a variable if it is a callable. Adding parenthesis will only result in an error.

Comment: @knbk Thanks for comment. You are right. I made wrong assumption, it works as in jinja2 templating where it is just opposite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, inside the loop `values` is the inner dict. So you can extract the values you need from there:

```
{{ category }} ({{ values.info }}) - {{ values.cats|join:", " }}
```

Comment: Nice solution with the join.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{% for category, item in cat.items %}
    {{ category }} ({{ item.info }}) - {% for val in item.cats %}{{ val }} {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

The dot notation will, in this order, try a dictionary lookup, an attribute lookup and a list-index lookup. That means `item.info` will be your info text, and `item.cats` will be your list of values.